# Ant Control Flow Break

Tags: ant, control-flow

Is there anything in Ant that allows me to halt the execution of an iterative segment like the `break` operation? Usage of external libraries is not  a problem.

As an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
<for list="1,2,3" param="iteration">
  <sequential>
    <if>
      <equals arg1="@{iteration}" arg2="3"/>
      <then>
        <!-- Break here -->
      </then>
    </if>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**Ant addon Flaka**](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) provides a break task, i.e. :

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
 <fl:for var="i" in=" list(1,2,3,4,5,6) ">
    <fl:echo>i = #{i}</fl:echo>
    <!-- also possible to use
     <fl:when test=" i eq 3 "> -->
     <fl:when test=" i == 3 ">
       <fl:break />
     </fl:when>
  </fl:for>
</project>
```

see [**Flaka Manual**](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/Manual) especially section 8. Repetative Tasks
for details about [**break task**](http://workbench.haefelinger.it/flaka/download/manual/flaka-1.2.2.html#task_break).